# Modal in bootstrap JSF Java EE project

Tags: javascript, java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I want to show a bootstrap modal in my JSP login page when the password is wrong. Otherwise the user is redirected (through faces-config.xml) to another JSP page. The username and password are validated in a managedbean that calls a remote bean.

I tried this with JavaScript but cannot get the desired result. This is my JSP login:

```
        <%-- BEGIN: Modal window --%>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <%--  END : Modal window --%>


        <br>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="panel-heading" align="center" style="opacity: 0.5;">
                    <h2><b><font color="white">RedCine<small><font color="white">Administrativo</font></small></font></b></h2>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="row">

                <div class="panel-body col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3 " align="center">

                    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 1%; margin-bottom: 40%;">

                        <div class="panel panel-success" align="left">


                            <div class="panel-heading form-group">
                                <b><font color="white">
                                        Ingrese usuario y contraseña</font> </b>
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body" >

                                <h:form id="PersonaBean">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="username">Usuario</label>
                                        <h:inputText value="#{persona.userName}" required="required" styleClass="form-control" />


                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password">Contraseña</label> 
                                        <h:inputSecret value="#{persona.password}" required="required" styleClass="form-control"  />
                                    </div>
                                        <h:commandButton id="btn_entrar" value="Entrar" action="#{persona.login()}" styleClass="btn btn-large btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" style="width: 100%; font-size:1.1em;"/>
                                </h:form>


                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>    

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer" align="center"><font style="color: #111">Copyright @2014  <a href="example.com">example.com</a>, All Rights Reserved. </font></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_entrar').click(function(){
           var resultado;
           if(resultado = 0)
           {
               $("#myModal").modal("show");
           }
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What happens when you click the button?

Comment: If the username and password are right, then I am redirectionated to a new page. But when the username and password are wrong the page doesn't show nothing.

Comment: So what are you trying to so when credentials are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your variable "resultado" is not getting set to any value, set the "debugger" keyword above "if(resultado = 0)" and check for that value.